# In AMQP 0.9 (rabbitmq) what are the app_id and cluster_id fields for

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to understand the app_id and cluster_id fields in an AMQP message. 
I have even tried reading the AMQP specification as defined on:

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html
  and
- http://www.amqp.org/resources/download

But it is unclear what the app_id and cluster_id fields are.
This remains equally unclear in AMQP 1.0 (which rabbitmq does not use by default)

(This in relation to my other question [AMQP (rabbitmq) identify origin of bad message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482885/amqp-rabbitmq-identify-origin-of-bad-message))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have so far comes from:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.extended.xml

Where it says:

```
<!--  For application use, no formal behaviour -->
<field name="app-id"     domain="shortstr" label="creating application   id"/>
<!--  Deprecated, was old cluster-id property -->
<field name="reserved" domain="shortstr" label="reserved, must be empty"/>
```

Whatever the cluster_id was for originally (identifying a cluster perhaps?) it is no longer used.

The comment notes "no formal behaviour" which I interpret as meaning that the header is permitted but it is entirely implementation defined and can be used for anything.
Given that you can also have custom headers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593804/rabbitmq-using-custom-headers-to-store-message-parameters) for example) it seems odd (bad protocol design?) to bother having any headers that do not have well defined semantics of their own.